# How to handle mongo db unable to connect issue with Mongoose and NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

Our Nodejs application uses Mongoose for MongoDB. Our application crashes when it unable to connect to MongoDB database. We are using `MongoLab`.

What are the best ways to handle database connect issue in Node JS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle error with the associated events:

```
// If the connection throws an error
connection.on('error',function (err) {
  // Do something here
});

// When the connection is disconnected
connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  // Do something else here
});
```

And, of course, when running a query, it's very recommended to always check `err` parameter of the callback function before going any further.

Comment: Thanks. It works great. But when the connection error, the request waits for response for a long time. Is there any way to timeout? is there any difference between connnection timeout and socket timeout?

Comment: As far as I know, a socket timeout implies a connection timeout. You can define the connection timeout by passing it as a option when calling `connect` : `mongoose.connect(url, { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 1000 }}}, function(err) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks. But MongoLab blogs talk about connection timeout and socket timeout separately http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/10/do-you-want-a-timeout/