# Error: connection timeout - expressjs mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to express/node and web programming in general. What is the best way to deal with this error when mongoose's mongodb connection times out, this is how I connect:

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'error connecting with mongodb database:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected to mongodb database');
});
```

This is the error when it times out while my server is running:

error connecting with mongodb database: Error: connection timeout
    at Db. (C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\webpages\000\lasttry\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:169:17)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Db.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Server.listener (C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\webpages\000\lasttry\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1798:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Server. (C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\webpages\000\lasttry\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:274:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pool. (C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\webpages\000\lasttry\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:335:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection. (C:\Users\Sean\OneDrive\webpages\000\lasttry\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)

Comment: When does the timeout occur? I've only ever had mongoose timeout if the node process gets interupted via my computer going to sleep.

Comment: I'm using mLab, its a cloud mongodb service. It seems to timeout randomly. I've only ever seen it happen twice but if I go to production and it happens that would be a nightmare lol.

Comment: (See the docs.)[http://docs.mlab.com/timeouts/#connection-timeout] You need to set a connection timeout value like in the answer I posted. Otherwise if there is any small issue with the connection, It won't wait before timing out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: No problem. Goodluck with your development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about on disconnect just reconnect to mongo. See below:

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'error connecting with mongodb database:'));

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected to mongodb database');
});    

db.on('disconnected', function () {
   //Reconnect on timeout
   mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
   db = mongoose.connection;
});
```

You can also set a timeout value on the connection.

```
mongoose.connect(url, { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 1000 }}}, function(err) { ... });
```

Also, make sure that mongo is still running on your machine. A connection timeout could mean mongo isn't running.

Reference: [Another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265810/how-to-handle-mongo-db-unable-to-connect-issue-with-mongoose-and-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check mongod is running.

   typing `mongo` in shell.
2. Add `connectTimeoutMS=300000` paramter for you uri.

   uri looks like `mongodb://localhost/collectionName?connectTimeoutMS=300000`